# encapsulate custom service from app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was reading stuff about defining my own services for angularjs. But in all examples the service is directly defined on my app via `myApp.factory(...)` call. See the offical docs for an [example](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services). I'm asking how I would define my service totally encapsualted from my app. So that I can share the service easily over different apps. I would like to simply include the .js file in which the service is defined and inject in into my app. Am I thinking wrong or is there a proper solution for this?

Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes either you can Define the global services or use factory pattern.
1) Defining the global service helps you in retrieving that global services into you multiple app.

```
function SimpleService($scope){
//define your service here
};
```

2) You can use factory design pattern and can define multiple services inside your factory and let say you wants to use your services in many apps(e.g. app1, app2, app3 etc.)

```
function SimpleFactory($scope){
//define your service here
};
app1.factory(SimpleFactory)
app2.factory(SimpleFactory)
app3.factory(SimpleFactory)
```

Comment: but when calling app.factory I have to provide 2 parameters which would not match with your example, right? Or does my factory function just has to follow some special rules?